# Messed up zoom navigation, need help!

Tags: 3d-view

I somehow pressed a key combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, the **zoom center** switched to the object origin (I was in 3D view) and now when I press middle mouse button and try to navigate the whole view **rotates around the object origin**. It **doesn't move** either when I select vertices in edit mode and press <kbd>.</kbd> again.

How to turn it back to normal? I already tried some options in view panel but *nothing* worked so far.

Edit: It also says "View offset is locked" when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll middle mouse button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out what exactly went wrong here. The **view was locked to the object**. So I somehow pressed a key combination that made the current object be the target for locked view.

If this occures to anyone else, press <kbd>N</kbd> whilst your mouse cursor is in 3D view window. Scroll through the opened panel, until you find the "view" one.

[image]

Now delete the target by clicking on the "x" as shown in the picture. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. That would bring back the 3D cursor to the origin, it will also  correct the zoom (in *object mode*)to see all the objects.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I luckily found the solution for my problem by trying a different way. I'll post the answer right away.

Comment: I now tried your solution; since the problem had a different reason it didn't work pressing shift-c. It just zoomed out but the view was still locked.

Comment: @xDonnervogelx i thought you some how went far away from the grid and kind of wondering if you have lost all your work shift-c could have brought you back to the grid