# I pressed alt+f to change the camera view and I do not know how to revert to the original camera MOVEMENT

Tags: camera

My camera movement (the viewport camera) in blender has become strange after pressing alt+f (and possibly other keys). When I scroll in with my mouse, the camera moves toward the origin instead of where my viewport is 'pointing'. The camera also rotates around the object that feels different than the original setting. I've already tried moving the cursor to center and pressing (.) on numpad but this hasn't worked. How do I completely reset camera movement?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution: [Messed up zoom navigation, need help!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52952/messed-up-zoom-navigation-need-help) (somehow I locked the view to the object which can be changed in the panel where you press N to hide and reveal it)